# how to get the hidden control value in xsl variable

Tags: xslt

I am new to xslt. My problem is I have a hidden control in one xslt file.

`<input type="hidden" name="Org" id="OID" value="5"/>`

I would like to select that value in  xsl variable in my another xslt file.

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:variable name="v1" select="//input[@type = 'hidden' and @id = 'OID']/@value"/>` should do to select the value from any input XML document the stylesheet processes. After your edit your question looks different however; you say you have 'a hidden control in one xslt file', and want to select that in a different xslt file. If one XSLT processes the other as the input then the path remains the same if there is a literal result element `<input type="hidden" name="Org" id="OID" value="5"/>` in the first XSLT document.

Comment: The hidden variable is in another xslt file. so that value is not coming over here.

Comment: Its not giving me the result

Comment: Consider to explain in more detail how you use the two XSLT documents. Do you process one as the input to the other? And show us the XSLT code, if the first one you process as the input puts the result elements in a namespace then my path does not work. Show us the code and we can make suggestions, the snippet you have posted does not enable us to help.

Comment: I am very sorry. Now my question : I have a variable in my javascript function. How select that variable value in xsl:valueof select.